# How to configure Spring Application Context in TestMode JAXRSCLIENT?

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

In the application the controllers are annotated with `javax.ws.rs` annotations. 
As far as I understand from the documentation as well as the sample project I must define a `BaseTestClass` as follows:

```
public class BaseTestClass {

    public static WebTarget webTarget;

    private static Server server;

    private static Client client;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setupTest() throws Exception {
        int port = findAvailableTcpPort(10000);
        URI baseUri = UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost").port(port).build();
        // Create Server
        server = new Server(port);
        // Configure ServletContextHandler
        ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(
                ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
        context.setContextPath("/");
        server.setHandler(context);
        // Create Servlet Container
        ServletHolder jerseyServlet = context
                .addServlet(org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.class, "/*");
        jerseyServlet.setInitOrder(0);

        // Tells the Jersey Servlet which REST service/class to load.        
       jerseyServlet.setInitParameter("jersey.config.server.provider.classnames",
                MyController.class.getCanonicalName());
        // Start the server
        server.start();
        ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
        client = ClientBuilder.newClient(clientConfig);
        webTarget = client.target(baseUri);
        try {
            server.start();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
        }
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void cleanupTest() {
        if (client != null) {
            client.close();
        }
        if (server != null) {
            try {
                server.stop();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

What is unclear is how to define my Spring configuration properly in this way.

The stub I have defined:

```
package contracts

import org.springframework.cloud.contract.spec.Contract

Contract.make {
    name("contract_update")
    request {
        method 'PUT'
        url '/xxx/v1/api'
        headers {
            header 'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.twitter-places-analyzer.v1+json'
        }
        body(file("update_request.json"))
    }
    response {
        status OK()
        headers {
            header 'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.twitter-places-analyzer.v1+json'
        }
        body(file("update_response.json"))
    }
}
```

When building, the test fails expecting 200 and receiving 404. My guess is that the application did not actually load properly due to failed application context loading and so no mapping is found.

To support my guess here is a log I found when starting the server:

```
Nov 12, 2019 6:27:36 PM org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.SpringComponentProvider initialize
SEVERE: Spring context lookup failed, skipping spring component provider initialization.
```

Comment: Please check this project out https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples/tree/master/producer_jaxrs

Comment: Thanks, but as I've stated in the question I've already used that sample project as reference (that is where I got the `BaseTestClass` code). And yet this example is very simple with no Java Config class of any kind. In my project in order to load the context I must provide a configuration class. My question is how to do so with the above `Jetty` framework.

Comment: Just setup your spring context as usual on a fixed port, then in the plaonold before method create a webtarget against that port like this e.g.  WebTarget webTarget = client.target("http://localhost:8080/JerseyDemos/rest").path("employees") where 8080 will be the random port

Comment: I apologize but I do not understand what you mean by "setup your spring context as usual". This way is unusual. The controller is being passed to `Jetty` server like so:`jerseyServlet.setInitParameter("jersey.config.server.provider.classnames",                MyController.class.getCanonicalName());` and looking at the `BaseTestClass` code I posed there is actually a line you are referring to: `webTarget = client.target(baseUri);`. But I still see no way for the framework to know my Spring configuration class. What am I missing?

Comment: Set your base class as if you were testing a normal spring boot application. You can check any other sample in the samples repo. Then you can create the webtarget as i mentioned previously. Since you're using Spring anyways why won't you use mock mvc approach?

Comment: I am honestly trying to make sense of the documentation and samples project but it is rather confusing. Where can I read about the mock mvc approach combined with `JAXRSCLIENT` test mode?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202260/discussion-between-nom1fan-and-marcin-grzejszczak).

Comment: Can we mark this as answered?

Comment: I apologize, but not yet. I was assigned to higher priority tasks so I did not get the chance to check the sample project you kindly added. I am expected to get back to it later this week. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Please check the newly added Spring Cloud Contract JaxRS with Spring sample (https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples/tree/master/producer_jaxrs_spring). For your convenience I'm copying its content here

The configuration

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ProducerWithJaxRsApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProducerWithJaxRsApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    PersonCheckingService personCheckingService() {
        return argument -> argument.getAge() >= 20;
    }
}

@Component
class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    JerseyConfig() {
        register(FraudDetectionController.class);
    }
}
```

The controller (`PersonCheckingService` is an interface with one method).

```
package com.example.beerapiproducerjaxrs;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

import com.example.beerapiproducerjaxrs.model.FraudCheck;
import com.example.beerapiproducerjaxrs.model.FraudCheckResult;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import static com.example.beerapiproducerjaxrs.model.FraudCheckStatus.NOT_OK;
import static com.example.beerapiproducerjaxrs.model.FraudCheckStatus.OK;

@RestController
@Path("/")
public class FraudDetectionController {

    private final PersonCheckingService service;

    public FraudDetectionController(PersonCheckingService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/check")
    @Produces("application/json;charset=utf-8")
    @Consumes("application/json;charset=utf-8")
    public FraudCheckResult fraudCheck(FraudCheck fraudCheck) {
        if (oldEnough(fraudCheck)) {
            return new FraudCheckResult(OK);
        }
        return new FraudCheckResult(NOT_OK);
    }

    private boolean oldEnough(FraudCheck fraudCheck) {
        return service.shouldGetBeer(fraudCheck);
    }

}
```

Base Class for tests

```
package com.example;

import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;

import com.example.beerapiproducerjaxrs.ProducerWithJaxRsApplication;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.web.server.LocalServerPort;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {ProducerWithJaxRsApplication.class},
        webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public abstract class BeerRestBase {

    @LocalServerPort int port;

    public WebTarget webTarget;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        this.webTarget = ClientBuilder.newClient().target("http://localhost:" + this.port + "/");
    }
}
```

And the plugin setup (Gradle)

```
contracts {
    packageWithBaseClasses = 'com.example'
    testMode = "JAXRSCLIENT"
}
```

And the plugin setup (Maven)

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud-contract.version}</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <packageWithBaseClasses>com.example</packageWithBaseClasses>
                <testMode>JAXRSCLIENT</testMode>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```